# NSDateFormatter not working in TextField

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

OK, I know I am missing something but I don't know what.

My NSDateFormmater comes up in the textField(personMonthdayTextField) with todays date but when I selected the datePicker  and input it into the textField, it comes up with the standard format with the hours, minutes, seconds which I don't need.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
NSDate* date = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MMM/yyyy"];
NSString* str = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"%@",str);
NSMutableArray *Arr=[str componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
personMonthdayTextField.text=[Arr objectAtIndex:0];
```

}

```
- (IBAction)done:(id)sender {


NSDate *dateSelected = [datepick date];
NSString *dateStamp = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@", dateSelected];
personMonthdayTextField.text = dateStamp;
```

}

Comment: You have to use `NSDateFormatter` to format the date in the `done:` method as well.

Answer (score 1):

This will give you date only

```
  NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 df.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterMediumStyle;
 datelabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
              [df stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]];
```

Adapt this for your code under your IBAction method

Comment: Why are you using `stringWithFormat:`? Just do `datelabel.text = [df stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];`

Answer (score 1):

just use `NSDateFormatter` in your `IBAction`

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];

NSDate *dateSelected = [datepick date];

personMonthdayTextField.text = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateSelected];
```

you can also tweak with formats of date give in Apple ios sdk ,easily to get desired format.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the day why don't you set the dateFormat as "dd", it would save the need to separate the components of dateString.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    NSDate* date = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd"];
    personMonthdayTextField.text = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
}

- (IBAction)done:(id)sender {

    NSDate *dateSelected = [datepick date];
    NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd"];
    personMonthdayTextField.text = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
}
```